# C# Mono Compile with Libraries folder?

Tags: c#, mono

I have a C# project like this:

```
root
|- libs
|  |- Compression.cs
|- test.cs
```

My compilation shell command is as follows:

```
mcs /out:test.exe *.cs
```

I'm getting the error message:

> The type or namespace name `Compression' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?

Any idea how I can tell mono to look in subfolders for C# libraries?

Comment: `*.cs` only matches test.cs. If you want to match all cs files, use `**/*.cs`.

Comment: @LexLi thanks! That does it alright!

Answer (score 0):

As [Lex Li](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11182/lex-li) said in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61700273/c-sharp-mono-compile-with-libraries-folder/61712678#comment109140399_61700273) on the question:

```
mcs /out:test.exe **/*.cs
```